# How do I use getCurrentWorkspace() inside of the jenkins test harness?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

In my dsl script I iterate over and read a bunch of files- these files are in the same repo as the seed job.

I do this to access them (works on jenkins):

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell()
myfiles = hudson.model.Executor.currentExecutor().getCurrentWorkspace().list('/myfolder/**')
```

How do I run this script on the test harness?

When I run this via the test harness I get an error.

```
Cannot invoke method getCurrentWorkspace() on null object
```

`readFileFromWorkspace()` from workspace seems to work but I see nothing like `listFilesFromWorkspace`. How do I get a list of files in a way that works on jenkins AND in the test harness??

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for this issue?